# Unable to install bundler

Tags: rubygems, redhat, gitlab

I am a newbie at installing software on linux. I am trying to install gitlab on Red Hat 6.3 as per the instructions on http://www.pickysysadmin.ca/2013/03/25/how-to-install-gitlab-5-0-on-centos-6/. The system already had ruby 1.9.3-p392 installed on it but I still went ahead and executed steps 6 and 8 in the installation guide link. However, when I try to execute step 9 (which installs the bundler) I get this error:

Fetching: bundler-1.3.5.gem (100%)
ERROR: While executing gem … (Errno::ENOENT)
No such file or directory – /data/apps/sa_gitlab/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/cache/bundler-1.3.5.gem

Do you know why this could be happening? I am not sure why the system would look up 1.9.1 version of ruby when step 8 shows the correct version of ruby. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have multiple version of bundler installed? What does `gem list` returns?

Comment: Yes. This was returned:                                         bigdecimal (1.1.0)
bundler (1.3.5, 1.3.4, 1.3.2)
highline (1.6.15)
io-console (0.3)
json (1.5.5)
minitest (2.5.1)
rake (10.0.3, 0.9.2.2)
rdoc (3.9.5)
rubygems-bundler (1.1.1)
rubygems-update (2.0.3)
rvm (1.11.3.6)

Comment: Ok, I was checkin http://tech-blog.blogbin.info/blog/2012/09/12/resolving-error-env-ruby-noexec-wrapper-no-such-file-or-directory/

Comment: So, does this mean that this step isn't required since the bundler is already installed?

Comment: It would means you need to uninstall the oldest version of the bundler, to be sure to have only one (the most recent)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a path issue.

While logged in as sa_gitlab perform the following:

```js
# Verify your using the right version of Ruby
[sa_gitlab@localhost~] which ruby
~/ruby/bin/ruby

[sa_gitlab@localhost~] ruby --version
ruby 1.9.3p392 (2013-02-22) [x86_64-linux]

[sa_gitlab@localhost~] which git
~/git/bin/git

[sa_gitlab@localhost ~] git --version
git version 1.8.2.3
```

If your output is different something went wrong with setting sa_gitlab's environment or you skipped the step of re-exporting $PATH

```js
# Re-export your PATH
[sa_gitlab@localhost~] PATH=$HOME/git/bin:$HOME/ruby/bin:$PATH:$HOME/bin;
```